# Find text of a column in other column with T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a doubt to find text from one column in a table; in other column from other table.

Imagine that you have this columns:

[image]

And you want to find the COMPLETE text of [A].X in [B].Y

And to discover where do you have the match. The colour yellow show this choice:
[image]

I have been thinking to use the "CONTAINS" function, but I think that it could be not the best idea. Because you have to write the text that you need to find (instead of a complete text of a column).

[CONTAINS T-SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/contains-transact-sql)

I thought that it could be like this:

```
Use AdventureWorks2012;  
GO  
SELECT [B].Y  
FROM Production.Product  
WHERE CONTAINS(([A].Y), [A].X);  

But it doesn't work.
```

Which is the best option?

I am using SQL SERVER V17.0

Thanks!!!

Comment: Do you expect "tea" to be found in "steam heat"? Can `Table A` strings contain whitespace, e.g. "brown sugar"? You may need to parse the second string into tokens before matching and perform the matching in a particular order, e.g. "brown sugar" before "sugar", to get the results you desire.

Comment: Yes. I expect "tea" to be found in "steam". It will be strange, but the people who introduce the data, could make a mistake and not put a whitespace between the words.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would go for `like`:

```
select b.y, a.x 
from b join
     a
     on b.y like '%' + a.x + '%' ;
```

There is not, however, a really efficient way to do this logic in SQL Server.

Comment: For the moment it is the easiest solution.
I have tried that and now is working ok.

Whit this method, i will detect whitespaces or not?

Thanks for the solution!

Regards

Comment: @jorge_vicente . . . I don't know what you mean by "detect whitespaces".

Comment: I try to explain if I search the "tea" word, Will I find this in "steam heat"? 
Or only in "s tea m heat"?


That is.. Will this query
 "like '%' + a.x + '%'" 
give me the result of "stem heat" or "s tea m heat"?

Thanks again!

Comment: @jorge_vicente . . . Yes, it will find those.  If that is your problem, then ask another question with better examples of what to match and what not to match.

Comment: Ok, perfect.

Thanks again Gordon!!

Comment: I have this query: `SELECT domain, nodeinfo_url FROM instances WHERE nodeinfo_url IS NOT NULL AND nodeinfo_url NOT LIKE '%' + domain + '%';` run on a SQLIte3 and I still get rows like: `gal.muri.zip|https://gal.muri.zip/api/nodeinfo/2.0.json`. I cannot find out why?

Comment: @roland… your comparison doesn’t have a.x.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I don't understand what you mean by this? Sure, my query is different and only has one table `instances`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick example searching a list of strings for a particular set of words defined in another table.  This example just searches through the system error messages text and looks for the words 'overflow' and 'CryptoAPI', but you'll substitute the words table with your 'A' and the 'sys.messages' table with your table 'B'

NOTE: this isn't the most efficient way to search large amounts of text.

```
-- CREATE TEMP TABLE WITH WORDS TO MATCH
CREATE TABLE #words (
    [Word] nvarchar(100)
)

-- SAMPLE STRINGS
INSERT INTO #words VALUES ('overflow')
INSERT INTO #words VALUES ('CryptoAPI')

-- SEARCH THROUGH SYSTEM ERROR MESSAGES FOR SAMPLE STRINGS
SELECT [W].[Word] AS 'Matched word'
    , [M].[text]
FROM [sys].[messages] AS [M]
    JOIN #words AS [W]
        ON [M].[text] LIKE '%' + [W].[Word] + '%'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE #TempA
(ColumnX VARCHAR(10)
);
CREATE TABLE #TempB
(ColumnY VARCHAR(100)
);
INSERT #TempA
VALUES('fish'),('burguer'),('sugar'),('tea'),('coffee'),('window'),('door');

INSERT #TempB
VALUES('I like potatoes'),('I eat sugar'),('I eat sugar with onions'), ('I have a car'),('I don''t like dogs');

SELECT *
FROM #TempB b
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM #TempA a WHERE CHARINDEX(a.ColumnX, b.ColumnY,1) > 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @GordonLinoff. `Like` is what i would also go for but i want to make one improvement in the answer provided.

```
CREATE TABLE #TempA (ColumnX VARCHAR(10));
CREATE TABLE #TempB (ColumnY VARCHAR(100));

INSERT #TempA
VALUES ('fish')
    ,('burguer')
    ,('sugar')
    ,('tea')
    ,('coffee')
    ,('window')
    ,('door');

INSERT #TempB
VALUES ('I steam potatoes')
    , ('I like potatoes')
    ,('I eat sugar')
    ,('I eat sugar with onions')
    ,('I have a car coffee')
    ,('I don''t like dogs')
    ,('Window is clean')
    ,('Open the door')
    ;


SELECT b.ColumnY
    ,a.ColumnX
FROM #TempB b
INNER JOIN #TempA a ON ' '+ b.ColumnY + ' ' LIKE '% ' + a.ColumnX + ' %'
```

This will take care of the TEA to be not found in STEAM.

Comment: It is a good solution too.
For the moment, I was trying to avoid Temp tables.

But I will keep in mind this solution.
Thanks!!!

Comment: @jorge_vicente , Temp tables are used here to just show the solution. You can replace #TempB and #TempA with Table B and Table A respectively in the SQL query. That will take care of whitespaces too.

Comment: Umm, sorry. You are right. I can replace with the "real" tables. Thanks !!